Did the original "Fury Road" actresses portray Immortan Joe's wives in the apple-offering scene in "Furiosa"?
In Furiosa: A Mad Max Saga (2024), the prequel to Mad Max: Fury Road (2015), there's a scene where a young Furiosa (played by Anya Taylor-Joy) offers apples to Immortan Joe's wives. (Not to be confused with the next scene where an older Furiosa, played by Charlize Theron, leads the wives to the war rig.)

The wives' faces in this scene are not clearly shown, unlike the later scene with Charlize Theron. This has led me to wonder about the actresses portraying the wives in this particular Furiosa scene.
Are they the same ones who played these roles in Fury Road (Rosie Huntington-Whiteley, Riley Keough, Zoë Kravitz, etc.)? If so, how was this achieved? Did they use old footage from Fury Road, or did they bring the actresses back for this brief scene (which I imagine would be quite expensive)? If it's not the original cast, who are the actresses playing these roles in Furiosa?

The end credit scenes contained deleted footage from Fury Road - https://www.thewrap.com/furiosa-credits-scene/. It's likely that this scene was a mixture of that footage, plus some digital creations
